# Bind static class in ViewModel class

Tags: .net, mvvm, bind, maui

I am playing around with the new Maps control from dotnet Maui. A simple example is to have the XAML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="SaRM.MainPage">

   <maps:Map x:Name="map" MapType="Street"/>

</ContentPage>
```

and with that I can access the "map" in the code behind cs file:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        var location = new Location(36.96, -122.0194);
        var mapSpan = new MapSpan(location, 0.01, 0.01);
        map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
    }
}
```

I would like to have a ViewModel to interact with the XAML but if I create a ViewModel class as:

```
public class MainViewModel
{

    public Map map;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var location = new Location(36.96, -122.0194);
        var mapSpan = new MapSpan(location, 0.01, 0.01);
        map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
    }

}
```

I get an error on "maps":

```
"Cannot declare variable of static type 'Map'"
```

That is because Map is a static class. How can I have a ViewModel class that binds to the Map element in XAML in that case?

Update:
Here is the Map class definition inside Microsoft.Maui.Maps:
[image]

Comment: Why does your VM have a reference to a UI element?

Comment: [`Map`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.maps.map?view=net-maui-7.0) is not a static class. You have some other `Map` type in scope?

Comment: Yes it is, I updated the question with the Map class definition.

Comment: @Jason, don't I need one to bind with the XAML Map element?

Comment: No.  A major concept of MVVM is that the VM is agnostic of the View

Comment: @rsc I would suggest you read a little about what MVVM is and how it works before doing this, UI element's and UI element types should never be directly referenced in your ViewModel, it ends up tightly coupling your View and VM which you are trying to avoid to begin with(concept of MVVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI elements and UI element types should not be directly referenced in your ViewModel,just as FreakyAli said.

Since `Map` is a UI element, so we cannot use it in our ViewModel directly.

You can define Map in `YourPage.xaml` and add other necessary data on your ViewModel.

For example:

you can add `Map` in `YourPage.xaml` and add `Positions` in View Model

```
         <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                  MapClicked="OnMapClicked"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
           
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>    
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
```

And add  `map.MoveToRegion` in `YourPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class PinItemsSourcePage : ContentPage
{
    public PinItemsSourcePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new PinItemsSourcePageViewModel();
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Location(39.8283459, -98.5794797), Distance.FromMiles(1500)));
    }

    void OnMapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MapClick: {e.Location.Latitude}, {e.Location.Longitude}");
    }
}
```

and define viewModel as follows:

```
public class PinItemsSourcePageViewModel
{
    int _pinCreatedCount = 0;
    readonly ObservableCollection<Position> _positions;

    public IEnumerable Positions => _positions;

    public ICommand AddLocationCommand { get; }
    public ICommand RemoveLocationCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ClearLocationsCommand { get; }
    public ICommand UpdateLocationsCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ReplaceLocationCommand { get; }

    public PinItemsSourcePageViewModel()
    {
        _positions = new ObservableCollection<Position>()
        {
            new Position("New York, USA", "The City That Never Sleeps", new Location(40.67, -73.94)),
            new Position("Los Angeles, USA", "City of Angels", new Location(34.11, -118.41)),
            new Position("San Francisco, USA", "Bay City", new Location(37.77, -122.45))
        };

        AddLocationCommand = new Command(AddLocation);
        RemoveLocationCommand = new Command(RemoveLocation);
        ClearLocationsCommand = new Command(() => _positions.Clear());
        UpdateLocationsCommand = new Command(UpdateLocations);
        ReplaceLocationCommand = new Command(ReplaceLocation);
    }

    void AddLocation()
    {
        _positions.Add(NewPosition());
    }

    void RemoveLocation()
    {
        if (_positions.Any())
        {
            _positions.Remove(_positions.First());
        }
    }

    void UpdateLocations()
    {
        if (!_positions.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        double lastLatitude = _positions.Last().Location.Latitude;
        foreach (Position position in Positions)
        {
            position.Location = new Location(lastLatitude, position.Location.Longitude);
        }
    }

    void ReplaceLocation()
    {
        if (!_positions.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        _positions[_positions.Count - 1] = NewPosition();
    }

    Position NewPosition()
    {
        _pinCreatedCount++;
        return new Position(
            $"Pin {_pinCreatedCount}",
            $"Desc {_pinCreatedCount}",
            RandomPosition.Next(new Location(39.8283459, -98.5794797), 8, 19));
    }
}
```

Fore more information, you can check document:[Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-8.0).

And above code is from official sample [WorkingWithMaps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps). Please pay attention to [PinItemsSourcePage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps/Views/PinItemsSourcePage.xaml) and [PinItemsSourcePageViewModel.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/UserInterface/Views/Map/MapDemo/WorkingWithMaps/ViewModels/PinItemsSourcePageViewModel.cs).